# send message between two android over local network(home-router)

Tags: java, android, android-networking

(1) i have router at home with which two android devices is connected through WiFi
(2) i want to send text message between two by getting device list from router and then sent message from source to destination

--i have searched a lot but did not find solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

and you will never find a solution .

First what you talking about is called hacking .

Second thing you can get the same result with some apps thats are currently available

for voice here some good apps:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidintercom

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.remaller.android.wifitalkie_lite

for chating :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ajaraj.wifisocial&hl=en

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.edinbros.testlanandroid

*note that i dont test them so give them a try .

i hope this help you :)